# I have a multiple variable function that I want to integrate in C (Used Trapezoidal Rule)

Tags: c, numerical-integration

I have to integrate with respect to E, with it's lower and upper limits as the first value of my log10(E) column that I'm printing for each source and upper limit as the last value of the same column.
My function is: ***fo* E^-spectralindex*exp(-tau1)***, which is nothing but my correctedDifflux defined here. [This function wrt E]. Here I have taken '**v**' and '**w**' as lower and upper limits for simplicity, but the integration that I'm carrying out here does not give correct values to these.
my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
float ebl(float zz, float ee) // Function ebl assigned for returning ta3 
value to be used later
{



float e1, e2, z1, z2, tau_a, tau_b, ta1, ta2, ta3, tau[500], z[500], e[500];
  int i, j, ii, jj;
float tauM[501][500];
FILE *fp;

 fp=fopen("tau_dominguez11_cta.txt", "r"); // Reading a file for creating a 
 matrix which has redshift and energy values

 for(i=0; i<501; i++)
   {
    for(j=0; j<400; j++)
   {
 fscanf(fp, "%f", &tauM[i][j]);

     }

   }
 fclose(fp);

 for(j=0; j<400; j++)
  {
  if(tauM[0][j]<=zz)
   {jj=j;}
 }

for(i=0; i<501; i++)
{

  if(tauM[i][0]<=ee)
  {ii=i;}
 }


 ta1=(zz-tauM[0][jj])*(tauM[ii][jj+1] -tauM[ii][jj])/(tauM[0][jj+1]-tauM[0]
 [jj]) + tauM[ii][jj]; //across zz

  ta2=(zz-tauM[0][jj])*(tauM[ii+1][jj+1] - tauM[ii+1][jj]) / (tauM[0][jj+1] 
 - tauM[0][jj]) + tauM[ii+1][jj]; //across zz

 ta3= (ta2 - ta1)*(ee-tauM[ii][0]) /(tauM[ii+1][0] - tauM[ii][0]) + ta1; 
 //across ee

 return ta3;
 }



float t(float E) // Defining to carry out the integration (help needed in 
this part) 
{
float fo, spectralindex, tau1;
return log10(fo * pow(E, -1*spectralindex) * exp(-1*tau1));
}

int main()
{
 FILE *fp1, *fp2,*files;
 int j,i,k;
 float fo;
 char source;
 float a,spectralindex,flux,E1,E2,E3,E4,x,logE,E,z,red,tau1;
 double diffflux,correctedDiffflux;
 float v=0.1, w=10, N=100,sum=0, h, p;

 E1=0.1, E2=100;
 E3=0.01, E4=10;
 float minLogE=log10(E3), maxlogE=log10(E4);

  int n=100;


fp1=fopen("actualvalues.txt", "r"); // reading flux and spectral index values for 3 sources




 for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{

 char filename[300];
 sprintf(filename,"source%d.txt",j);


  files=fopen(filename,"w");


   fscanf(fp1, "%s %e %f %f\n", &source,  &flux, &spectralindex,&red);

  a=-1*(spectralindex)+1;

  fo=(flux*a)/(pow(E2, a) - pow(E1, a));


   x=(log10(E4/E3))/n;
   logE=minLogE;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)

   {


    logE=logE+x;

   E=pow(10,logE);



   diffflux=fo*(pow(E,-1*(spectralindex)));

  tau1=ebl(red,E);
   correctedDiffflux=diffflux*exp(-1*tau1);

  h = (w-v) / N;
   p = t(v);

   for(k=1; k<N; k++)
  {
     p=p+2*t(v+k*h);
   }
   p = p+t(w);
   p = p*(h/2);  // p is the integration variable

     fprintf(files,"%f    %f    %f    
      %f\n",log10(E),log10(diffflux),log10(correctedDiffflux),p);

      }
     }
       fclose(fp1);
      fclose(fp2);
    fclose(files);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function where you comment that you need some help,

```
float t(float E) // Defining to carry out the integration (help needed in this part) 
{
    float fo, spectralindex, tau1;
    return log10(fo * pow(E, -1*spectralindex) * exp(-1*tau1));
}
```

the three local variables are *uninitialised*. They have no connection with similar variables in other functions.

If you enable compiler warnings, this should inform you.

Also I suggest you stop using `float` in favour of `double` unless there are very good reasons not to. Twentieth century textbook?

Comment: Actually, I had tried that too, same result. As in the integration part does not work `double t(double E, double fo, double spectralindex, double tau1)
{

return(fo * pow(E, -1*spectralindex) * exp(-1*tau1));
}
`